# How to reuse data from a resource in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to reuse the string from addresses in dns_aaaa_record_set in dns_ptr_record, how?

```
resource "dns_aaaa_record_set" "app-stage-dns" {
  count     = length(var.datacenter)
  zone      = format("%s.", var.dns_zone)
  name      = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.mydomain"
  addresses = [replace(openstack_compute_instance_v2.app-stage[count.index].access_ip_v6, "/\\[|\\]/", "")]
  ttl       = 300
}

resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr" {
  count = length(var.datacenter)
  zone  = format("%s.", var.dns_ptr_zone)
  ptr   = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.mydomain"
  name  = <dns_aaaa_record_set[addresses]>
  ttl   = 300
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you could do the following:

```
resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr" {
  count = length(var.datacenter)
  zone  = format("%s.", var.dns_ptr_zone)
  ptr   = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.mydomain"
  name  = dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses[0]
  ttl   = 300
}
```

You have to be careful about `name`. `addresses` in your `dns_aaaa_record_set` is a list, and `name` must be only a string, not list.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I got another issue after this:
Error: Invalid index

  on app-stage.tf line 93, in resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr":
  93:   name  = dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses[0]
    |----------------
    | count.index is 1
    | dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns is tuple with 2 elements

This value does not have any indices.

Comment: @user3297323 you can try tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns)[count.index].addresses[0]

Comment: That gave me:

Error: Invalid index

  on app-stage.tf line 94, in resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr":
  94:   name  = tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns)[count.index].addresses[0]
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns is tuple with 2 elements

This value does not have any indices.

Comment: @user3297323 I see. I think it should be `tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses)[0]`. The `tolist` closing parenthesis was in the wrong place.